# Is this a valid way to derive the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In both Galilean and Special Relativity the laws of physics are the same in all reference frames, and similarly they are the same for all points in space.  Not all objects have the same mass, so in general not all objects can have an equal contribution to the velocity of a system, but what they can contribute equally to a system is its momentum.  Since $\vec{p}\propto{\vec{v}}$, it follows that if the laws of physics are the same for all velocities they are also the same for all momentums.  Since the laws of physics are the same for all points in space, the universe is symmetric with respect to position space, and similarly since the laws of physics are the same for all points in in momentum space the universe has momentum space symmetry.

This means that if there is a position space wavefunction it must be symmetric with respect to momentum space, and the only way for it to be symmetric with respect to momentum space is if it is exactly the same for all points in momentum space.  Similarly a momentum space wavefunction must be symmetric with respect to position space, and the only way to satisfy that requirement is to be exactly the same for all points in position space.  Since the position space wavefunction is related to the probability of a particle being at a given position, if it is the same for all points in momentum space, then that means that if you perfectly measure a particle in position space, the probability of a particle being at any point in momentum space will be exactly the same meaning that it has an infinite uncertainty in momentum space.  Similarly if the momentum space wavefunction is exactly the same for all points in position space, that means that if you perfectly measure the particle in momentum space, the probability is the same for all points in position space, and so there is an infinite uncertainty in position.

The question is, is this a valid way to derive the uncertainty principle?

Comment: I do not see a derivation of $\sigma_x \sigma_p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$ here.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't derive the uncertainty principle (or the commutation relations of the position and the momentum operators from which the uncertainty principle follows) using simply symmetry arguments. In particular, the symmetries that you list are also present in classical mechanics. If they were to imply an uncertainty principle then classical mechanics would also have an uncertainty principle, which it clearly doesn't. OK, that's the basic reason as to why it is a foregone conclusion that what you are hoping to prove cannot be proved.

However, I will still point out, for the sake of completeness, some of the specific mistakes in your actual argument:

> Since the laws of physics are the same for all points in space, the universe is symmetric with respect to position space, and similarly since the laws of physics are the same for all points in momentum space the universe has momentum space symmetry.

- These claims are not true. The universe is not symmetric in position space, to wit, London is not New York. Your first statement is the correct statement that the laws of physics are the same at all points in space. However, this does not imply that the universe itself has to be symmetric in position space. There can be such solutions, e.g., the FRW cosmology, but it is not an implication of the laws of physics being symmetric in position space.
- Secondly, it is not accurate to say that the laws of physics are the same for all momenta. What is correct is that the laws of physics are the same for all inertial observers. So, if you transform all dynamical observables in a system appropriately corresponding to a Galilean/Lorentz boost then the Lagrangian would remain invariant. However, it does not mean that physics is invariant under translations in momentum space.

> Similarly a momentum-space wavefunction must be symmetric with respect to position space, and the only way to satisfy that requirement is to be exactly the same for all points in position space.

- OK, I don't know what you mean by momentum-space wavefunction being symmetric w.r.t. position space. Momentum-space wavefunction of which state? Every state? But more importantly, a momentum-space wavefunction of a state $\vert\psi\rangle$ is simply given by $\psi(p)=\langle p\vert\psi\rangle$ so unless $\vert\psi\rangle$ itself is defined with reference to some particular position, this is trivially symmetric w.r.t. position space.

---

Finally, I will mention it again that the real derivation of the uncertainty principle comes from the commutation relations of operators in quantum mechanics. And any attempt to derive this fundamentally quantum mechanical fact from purely classical arguments has a lower chance of succeeding than an attempt to trisect an angle using only a compass and a straight edge. ;-)

Comment: Upvoted.  But if I knew for certain that tomorrow, either someone would derive the uncertainty principle from classical considerations or someone would figure out how to trisect an arbitrary angle with straightedge and compass, I'd bet on the former.

Comment: @WillO Well, what is life without hyperbole! ;-)